# Reading Null values in field using ArcPy SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I'm using a Python script with ArcGIS 10 to count the number of unique string values in a feature class. My script works if there are values in the field but if there are any NUll values in the field it crashes. Any Ideas?

My code is below:

```
import arcpy
import operator

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
stringField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)


stringList = [row.getValue(stringField) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor
                                       (inTable, "", "",stringField)]
```

Comment: Try using the SearchCursor command with no parameters besides inTable:
    stringList = [row.getValue(stringField) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(inTable)]

Comment: Does the script fail during the loop through the SearchCursor or does it fail later on?  It seems that the list comprehension should be able to handle collecting `None` values, which is the Python representation of `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

Null values are equal to the python None
so you could also handle null values like this

```
if row.getValue(stringField) == None:
    do something
if row.getValue(stringField) != None:
    do something else
```

Answer (score 2):

Use isNull(field_name) method before getting values. For further info see this [help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)

Comment: Do you mean I need to count the null values seperately?